# Windows Phone 8 Push notification doesn't work - app manifest fault?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, push-notification, manifest

I'm building app for Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 that uses push notification. I have configured everything, as in MSDN. Web service is claiming that pushes are send, but phone can't detect them. The only think i haven't done is setting identity manually, because putting them in AppManifest.xml has been stopping my app working(infinite loading).

> To set your application's identity values manually, open the AppManifest.xml file in a text editor and set these attributes of the  element using the values shown here.

I don't know if this was the problem, so I also give some code, which is supposed to make notifications work.

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;
            pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(ChannelName);
            if (pushChannel != null)
            {
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
                pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
            }
            else
            {
                pushChannel=new HttpNotificationChannel(ChannelName);
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
                pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
                pushChannel.Open();
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();


            }
```

Comment: Have the same problem. I found that you can't set it manually, at least in a Silverlight application, because the AppManifest.xml has a different structure and the <Identity> tag causes the XML parsing to fail, and as a consequence the APP fails to load.
The 'menu' option is unavailable to us as well because out app is 8.0 compatible, and the 'Store' menu is enabled only to 8.1 Apps.